# How to clone a maven project from github using IDEA?

Tags: git, maven, intellij-idea

I need to study a demo project from a Github repositary using IDEA. The options is proposed by IDEA are:

1. Create a new project from VCS -> input URL
2. Create a new project from existing source -> Maven

So the question is: if I choose 1. is it enough? Will IDEA recognize a "maven project" automatically? Or should I clone the project manually ( from CLI) and then use the 2nd way?

Comment: You can always just try both options.  My _guess_ is that option #1 would work if you have the Git plugin turned on.

Comment: I usually clone the repo in the command line, and then select "File" -> "Open", and the select the pom.xml-file of the project. IDEA then gives me a choice on how to open, as project or file, select project.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled into same situation, have found a workaround:

1. Do what you did before
2. Close cloned project, then select File -> New -> Project from existing sources
3. Agree to override project files if needed

That way IDEA will offer you to import your project as a maven project

HTH